# ANTLR4 grammar issue

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have following grammar in ANTLR4

```
grammar DEF;

def
:
    'DEF' vartypes ID ';'
;

ID
:
    (
        'A' .. 'Z'|'a'..'z'
    )+
;

vartypes
:
    INT
    | REAL
;

INT:'INT';
REAL:'REAL';

VARIABLE
:
    (
        'A' .. 'Z'
        | 'a' .. 'z'
        | '0' .. '9'
        | '_'
        | '-'
    )+
;

fragment VARTYPEREAL
:
    'REAL'
;

fragment VARTYPEINT
:
    'INT'
;

LINENUMBER
:
    'N' INTVALUE
;

INTVALUE
:
    (
        '-'
    )?
    (
        '0' .. '9'
    )+
;

WS
:
    (
        ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\n'
        | '\r'
    )+ -> skip
;
```

And when I parse the string 'DEF REAL test;' I get the following error:

```
line 1:4 missing {'INT', 'REAL'} at 'REAL'
```

line 1:9 extraneous input 'test' expecting ';'

But, when I change my grammar to

```
grammar DEF;

def
:
    'DEF' vartypes ID ';'
;

ID
:
    (
        'A' .. 'Z'|'a'..'z'
    )+
;

vartypes
:
    'INT'
    | 'REAL'
;

VARIABLE
:
    (
        'A' .. 'Z'
        | 'a' .. 'z'
        | '0' .. '9'
        | '_'
        | '-'
    )+
;

fragment VARTYPEREAL
:
    'REAL'
;

fragment VARTYPEINT
:
    'INT'
;

LINENUMBER
:
    'N' INTVALUE
;

INTVALUE
:
    (
        '-'
    )?
    (
        '0' .. '9'
    )+
;

WS
:
    (
        ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\n'
        | '\r'
    )+ -> skip
;
```

everything  is fine. Where I'm wrong in the grammar 1?

Comment: As a comment, it is not easy to spot the difference between your grammars. To avoid the votes to close next time, describe what exactly you changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your first grammar `INT` and `REAL` rules come after `ID`, so strings "INT" and "REAL" are matched with `ID` rule. In your second grammar you use strings instead, which (in mixed grammars like you have) create implicit lexer rule that take precedence to the explicit rules.

To fix the first grammar move `INT` and `REAL` above `ID` rule.